# move file from azure data lake Gen 1 to a temp directory using python

Tags: python, azure-data-lake

how to move file from azure data lake Gen 1 to a temp directory using python?
I need to find each file in the ADL, move it to temp directory to decrpt it and read it.

i am using

```
azure.datalake.store import core
core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, 'store_name')

#create a temp directory
 with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
```

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? What do you mean `a temp directory`? The directory on local disk?

Comment: Hi Jim,
yes, i am creating temporary directory on local. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithreaded

##auth
adlCreds = lib.auth(tenant_id = tenant,
                client_secret = client_secret,
                client_id = client_id,
                resource = RESOURCE)
subscriptionId = 'FILL-IN-HERE'
adlsAccountName = 'FILL-IN-HERE'

## Create a filesystem client object
adlsFileSystemClient = core.AzureDLFileSystem(adlCreds, store_name=adlsAccountName)


## Download a file
multithread.ADLDownloader(adlsFileSystemClient, lpath='<local path>', rpath='<path on adls>', nthreads=64, overwrite=True, chunksize=4194304,buffersize=4194304, blocksize=4194304)

##Move file between locations on ADL
adlsFileSystemClient.mv('<Source Path>','Destination path')
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-python)

Comment: Thanks Jim, this should work. i will let you know how it goes.